# Failed to import bridging header in xcode 8

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode8, xcode7.3, bridging-header

I have updated my project from xcode 7.3 to xcode 8  that project is  mixture of cordova and native .I am getting error of Bridge Header not found .. I have tried many solutions even I have made a new  bridge header many times but getting same error always

error

> **:0: error: failed to import bridging header**

Comment: I am just want to  update my project from xcode 7.3 to xcode 8 ..but i am getting  a error written above ..it is  cordova based project which also have native files of objective -c as well as swift also ...i am getting error in xcode 8 only

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1057   --this type of same error i am getting

Answer (score -1):

A possible cause for this would be that the Bridging Header is not properly connected to your project.

Solution 1:
I strongly recommend deleting your current Bridging Header and then go to File -> New File -> Objective-C Source File(.m). When you create the file it will ask you if it should create a new Bridging Header. Click Create. After that, put your #import statements in the new header, and delete the .m file, which is unnecessary. Then, you're good to go.

Solution 2:
To check if your Bridging Header is connected properly to your project, go to Project -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - General. There, you will have the option Objective-C Bridging Header.